# RestTemplate. Unmarshalling JaxB object from octet-stream

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

I have need to send request to service and parse response as a jaxb object. This is service call code:

```
        ProviderResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(
            URL,
            request,
            ProviderResponse.class
        );
```

`request` and `response` are JAXB objects. This is spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
            <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>


<bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.service.data.ProviderRequest</value>
            <value>com.service.data.ProviderResponse</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

When I run this code, I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.service.data.ProviderResponse] and content type [application/octet-stream]
```

I tried to do this way:

```
        String responseStr = restTemplate.postForObject(
            URL,
            request,
            String.class
        );

        ProviderResponse response = stringToJaxb(responseStr, ProviderResponse.class);
```

and it works fine, but I don't think that it's a good solution.
Maybe it can be fixed by spring config?

UPD

ProviderResponse class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "header",
    "body"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "providerResponse")
public class ProviderResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String header;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ProviderResponse.Body body;


    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }


    public void setHeader(String value) {
        this.header = value;
    }


    public ProviderResponse.Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }


    public void setBody(ProviderResponse.Body value) {
        this.body = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "code",
        "serviceStatus"
    })
    public static class Body {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected String code;
        protected String serviceStatus;


        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(String value) {
            this.code = value;
        }

        public String getServiceStatus() {
            return serviceStatus;
        }


        public void setServiceStatus(String value) {
            this.serviceStatus = value;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For RestTemplate it doesnt use the converters configured in the application context. You have to create a list of HttpMessageConverters and provide it in the RestTemplate constructor as follows

```
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingConverter = new   MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ProviderRequest.class ,ProviderResponse.class);
marshallingConverter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
marshallingConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM , MediaType.APPLICATION_XML , MediaType.TEXT_XML));
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(Collections.singletonList(converter));
```

Comment: Can I do it in spring configuration?

Comment: It still doesn't work. `messageConverter.canRead(this.responseClass, contentType)` in `HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(...)` returns `false` for  `ProviderResponse` and `application/octet-stream`

Comment: Post your ProviderResponse class

Answer (score 1):

Set the supported media types on the MarshallingHttpMessageConverter as follows

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
            <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller"/>
            <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
               <list>
                  <value>application/xml</value>
                  <value>text/xml</value>
                  <value>application/octet-stream</value>
               </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I get `restTemplate.getMessageConverters()` there are no `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` . There are `Jaxb2RootElementHttpConverter` but it hasn't `octet-stream` in supported media types list.

Comment: For RestTemplate it doesnt use the converters configured in the application context. You have to create a list of HttpMessageConverters and provide it in the RestTemplate constructor as follows MarshallingHttpMessageConverter converter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();converter.setMarshaller(...);converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));